# My EF Core query is not showing the results I want

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm having a problem when filtering my EF Core results. My query is plain and simple, yet the results are not what I expected. The code shown here are the queries I've tried so far, yet the items that I don't want to be shown are still included in the results.

Then items with P8, DG, DJ, DH, DM should not be included in the query but when I run the app document types with P8, DG, DJ, DH, DM is still included.

```
@foreach (var cmdm in ViewBag.BSID_UNPAID)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@cmdm.BLART</td>
        <td>@cmdm.KUNNR</td>
        <td>@cmdm.BUDAT</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>@cmdm.SGTXT</td>
        <td>@cmdm.DMBTR</td>
    </tr>
}
```

First code I've tried

```
ViewBag.BSID_UNPAID = _context.BSIDs.Where(i => 
        (i.UMSKZ == "" && i.BLART != "P8") ||
        (i.UMSKZ == "" && i.BLART != "DG") ||
        (i.UMSKZ == "" && i.BLART != "DJ") ||
        (i.UMSKZ == "" && i.BLART != "DH") ||
        (i.UMSKZ == "" && i.BLART != "DM")).OrderByDescending(e => e.ZFBDT);
```

Second code I've tried

```
ViewBag.BSID_UNPAID = _context.BSIDs.Where(a => 
         a.UMSKZ == "" && 
               (a.BLART != "P8" ||
                a.BLART != "DG" ||
                a.BLART != "DJ" ||
                a.BLART != "DH" ||
                a.BLART != "DM")).OrderByDescending(e => e.ZFBDT);
```

[image]

Items with DM Doc Type should not be included, but in the screenshot above, they are still included.

I hope someone can help me figure out which part of the code I'm wrong.

Comment: `(X!=A) || (X!=B)` would always be true. But you haven't explained what you want.

Comment: Firstly, you left the most important part of the question out, which is curious to say the least.... Also this is a Boolean Algebra / Propositional Logic 101 problem. You just need to think through the consequences of your ors and ands. As such this should nearly be closed as a typo

Comment: If you are serious about getting this answered, give a simple structure with test data, and show what you would expect out from this query. We call this a [mcve] , also take a read of [ask]

Comment: @00110001 hi.. sure.. I will edit my post to add some screenshots, thank you! :)

Comment: No, not screen shots, [mcve] use .net fiddle if you have to

Answer (score 0):

As @Jeremy Lakeman said in comment, true Or false always return true. So, the second part is always true.

```
(a.BLART != "P8" ||
 a.BLART != "DG" ||
 a.BLART != "DJ" ||
 a.BLART != "DH" ||
 a.BLART != "DM")
```

And the second query equals

```
ViewBag.BSID_UNPAID = _context.BSIDs.Where(a => a.UMSKZ == "").OrderByDescending(e => e.ZFBDT);
```

> Then items with P8, DG, DJ, DH, DM should not be included in the query

So, all these conditions should be connected by logical AND operator.

```
ViewBag.BSID_UNPAID = _context.BSIDs.Where(a => 
     a.UMSKZ == "" && 
     a.BLART != "P8" &&
     a.BLART != "DG" &&
     a.BLART != "DJ" &&
     a.BLART != "DH" &&
     a.BLART != "DM").OrderByDescending(e => e.ZFBDT);
```